# Rails make flash[] show on Javascript reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, reload

I have an application based on Paperclip uploads and downloads.   I have my download links point to a download action in the controller that is forced into a new window by Javascript.  However, the controller in this case also sets some flash[] messages.   They don't show up in the main window unless I do a Ctrl+R.   I tried to replicate this with a javascript `location.reload` on that window but then the flash doesn't show.   Why is the Javascript reload different than Ctrl+R?

Comment: Did you mean `location.reload()`, as if to call the function?

Answer (score 4):

Set the flash message in the controller before calling .reload()

```
def controller_action
  flash[:notice] = "You have been successfully uploaded an image"
  render :js => 'window.location.reload()'
end
```

Note: The render :js reload() is being eval'd on the client based on initial jquery $.post request to controller_action with dataType: 'script'.